# c++ if в switch с использованием string

Tags: c++

if string обработать может, а switch не может.
но использовать if, как-то не красиво.

можно ли как-то упростить код
можно ли как-то это исправить?
код:

```
#include "pch.h" //
#include <iostream> //
#include <string> //
#include <ctime> //
#include <conio.h> //

using namespace std;

bool play = false;
string languages = "en";
int graphics = 1; 

enum dir:char
{ 
    _left = 'd', 
    _right = 'a', 
    _up = 'w',
    _down = 's'
};

int yPlayer = 8, xPlayer = 0; // player:cordinats

void Menu()
{
    system("cls");
    string menu;
    _menu:

    if (languages == "en")
    {
        cout << "Play" << endl;
        cout << "Setting" << endl;
        cout << "Exit" << endl;
        cin >> menu;

        if (menu == "play")
        {
            play = true;
        }
        else if (menu == "setting")
        {
            system("cls");
            cout << "languages: " << languages << endl;
            cout << "graphics: " << graphics << endl;

            cout << endl;
            cout << "keyboard: " << endl;
            cout << "left: " << _left << endl;
            cout << "right: " << _right << endl;
            cout << "up: " << _up << endl;
            cout << "down: " << _down << endl;

            cin >> menu;

            if (menu == "lang")
            {
                cout << "English: en" << endl;
                cout << "Russia: ru" << endl;

                cin >> menu;

                if (menu == "en")
                {
                    languages = "en";
                }
                else if (menu == "ru")
                {
                    languages = "ru";
                }
                goto _menu;
            }
            else if (menu == "graphics")
            {
                cout << "1" << endl;
                cout << "2" << endl;
                cout << "3" << endl;

                cin >> menu;

                if (menu == "1") graphics = 1;
                else if (menu == "2") graphics = 2;
                else if (menu == "3") graphics = 3;
                goto _menu;
            }
            else if (menu == "keyboard")
            {
                cout << "left: " << endl;
                cout << "right: " << endl;
                cout << "up: " << endl;

                cin >> menu;

                if (menu == "left")
                {
                    cout << "left" << endl;
                    //cin >> _left;
                }
                else if (menu == "right")
                {
                    cout << "right" << endl;
                    //cin >> _right;
                }
                else if (menu == "up")
                {
                    cout << "up" << endl;
                    //cin >> _up;
                }
                cout << "Временно не доступно" << endl;
                system("pause");
            }
            goto _menu;
        }
        else if (menu == "Exit")
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            goto _menu;
        }
    }
    else if (languages == "ru")
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
        cout << "Играть" << endl;
        cout << "Настройки" << endl;
        cout << "Выход" << endl;

        cin >> menu;

        if (menu == "play")
        {
            play = true;
        }
        else if (menu == "setting")
        {
            system("cls");
            cout << "Языки: " << languages << endl;
            cout << "Графика: " << graphics << endl;

            cout << endl;
            cout << "Клавиатура: " << endl;
            cout << "лево: " << _left << endl;
            cout << "право: " << _right << endl;
            cout << "вверх: " << _up << endl;

            cin >> menu;

            if (menu == "lang")
            {
                cout << "Англиский: en" << endl;
                cout << "Русский: ru" << endl;

                cin >> menu;

                if (menu == "en")
                {
                    languages = "en";
                }
                else if (menu == "ru")
                {
                    languages = "ru";
                }
                goto _menu;
            }
            else if (menu == "graphics")
            {
                cout << "1" << endl;
                cout << "2" << endl;
                cout << "3" << endl;

                cin >> menu;

                if (menu == "1") graphics = 1;
                else if (menu == "2") graphics = 2;
                else if (menu == "3") graphics = 3;
                goto _menu;
            }
            else if (menu == "keyboard")
            {
                cout << "лево: " << endl;
                cout << "право: " << endl;
                cout << "вверх: " << endl;

                cin >> menu;

                if (menu == "left")
                {
                    cout << "лево" << endl;
                    //cin >> _left;
                }
                else if (menu == "right")
                {
                    cout << "право" << endl;
                    //cin >> _right;
                }
                else if (menu == "up")
                {
                    cout << "вверх" << endl;
                    //cin >> _up;
                }
                cout << "Временно не доступно" << endl;
                system("pause");
            }
            goto _menu;
        }
        else if (menu == "exit")
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            goto _menu;
        }
    }
}

void Game()
{
    system("cls");

    for (int y = -1; y <= 9; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x <= 167; x++)
        {
            // y : x
            if (   y == 9 && x == x // 167 x 1

                || y == 7 && x == 5
                || y == 7 && x == 6
                || y == 7 && x == 7 // 1 x 5
                || y == 7 && x == 8
                || y == 7 && x == 9

                || y == 6 && x == 10 // 1 x 1

                || y == 7 && x == 11
                || y == 7 && x == 12
                || y == 7 && x == 13 // 1 x 5
                || y == 7 && x == 14
                || y == 7 && x == 15

                || y == 8 && x == 15 // 1 x 1

                || y == 8 && x == 25 // 2 x 1
                || y == 7 && x == 25

                ) 
            { 
                cout << "+"; // render world

                if (yPlayer == y && xPlayer == x)
                {
                    if (_kbhit()) // player:keyboard
                    {
                        switch (_getch())
                        {
                        case _left:
                            xPlayer -= 1;
                            break;

                        case _right:
                            xPlayer += 1;
                            break;

                        case _up:
                            yPlayer += 2;
                            break;

                        case _down:
                            yPlayer -= 2;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (yPlayer == y && xPlayer == x) { cout << "#"; } // render player
            else                                   { cout << " "; } // render world

            //cheak: y
            if (yPlayer < -2)       { yPlayer += 2; }
            else if (yPlayer > 9)   { yPlayer -= 2; }

            //cheak: x
            else if (xPlayer < 0)  { xPlayer += 1; }
            else if (xPlayer > 167) { xPlayer -= 1; }
        }
    }

    if (_kbhit()) // player:keyboard
    {
        switch (_getch())
        {
        case _left:
            xPlayer += 1;
            break;

        case _right:
            xPlayer -= 1;
            break;

        case _up:
            yPlayer -= 2;
            break;

        case _down:
            yPlayer += 2;
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    Menu();
    while (play) Game();
}
```

Comment: Непосредственно в `switch` - разве что используя какой-то целочисленный хеш :) Но есть вариант - например, записать строки для сравнения в массив и выполнять в нем поиск, или, например, использовать полиморфизм... И, кстати, вовсе незачем все в одну кишку вытягивать, активнее используйте те же функции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По сути, цитирую [ответ с cyberforum.ru](http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread1970114.html):

```cpp
std::map<std::string,std::function<void()>> dict{
        {"one",[](){std::cout<<"one";}},
        {"two",[](){std::cout<<"two";}},
        {"three",[](){std::cout<<"three";}}};
    std::string word;
    std::cin>>word;
    dict[word]();
```

На подробные пояснения пока что нет времени, если они понадобятся, пишите в комментарии. Если кратко, то после `[]()`  в фигурных скобках все действия по тому слову, которое написано в кавычках перед этим.

Comment: я очень рад что ты помог, но вот проблема в том что function, dict подчеркиваются красным, map тоже ( но после подключения библиотеки map: map за работало). буду очень рад если по можешь

Comment: @СлаваНосков Подключите functional (`#include<functional>`)

Comment: @СлаваНосков А `dict` – название переменной. Перестанет подчеркиваться после того, как все типы будут определены

Answer (score 2):

Вы не можете использовать в операторе switch *condition*-выражение, имеющее тип `std::string`, так как на данный тип налагаются некоторые ограничения, описанные в [пункте 8.4.2.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.switch#2) стандарта C++:

> The condition shall be of integral type, enumeration type, or class
>   type. If of class type, the condition is contextually implicitly
>   converted to an integral or enumeration type. If the (possibly
>   converted) type is subject to integral promotions, the condition is
>   converted to the promoted type